# How can I get the value of various FormStartPosition members?

Tags: c#, winforms

Forms have a property called `StartPosition` which I can set to one of the members of the `FormStartPosition` enum. For example is one of them called `WindowsDefaultLocation` and another is called `CenterParent`.

Now lets say I wanted to create a button that moved a form to its windows default position, to the center of the screen or center of its parent. In this case the form would already be on screen, so the `StartPosition` property wouldn't be of much use, so I would need to get that value in a different way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use the FormStartPosition enum once the form has already loaded.

You will need to set the 'Location' property - coordinates of the top left corner of the form as per your needs.

Comment: Yes, that of course makes sense. But is there a different way of getting that value for i.e. `Location` that *would* have been used *if* `StartPosition` and `FormStartPosition` had been used?